# configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs. (Installing GAP on Arch Linux)

Tags: linux, gcc, archlinux, configure

I am trying to install GAP on Arch Linux (on my Steam Deck). Please don't ask why, I am not able to answer this question. When trying to run the configure script, I can get some strange C error. When googling the error, I only get dubious results for various systems. Any help would be appreciated :)

Output ./configure:

```
(deck@steamdeck gap-4.11.1)$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/home/deck/gap/gap-4.11.1':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GAP configure 4.11.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = steamdeck
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.13.0-valve10.3-1-neptune-02176-g5fe416c4acd8
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 23 Feb 2022 20:55:35 +0000

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/bin/site_perl
PATH: /usr/bin/vendor_perl
PATH: /usr/bin/core_perl


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2702: checking build system type
configure:2716: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2736: checking host system type
configure:2749: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2819: checking for gcc
configure:2835: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2846: result: gcc
configure:3075: checking for C compiler version
configure:3084: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 11.1.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3095: $? = 0
configure:3084: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++,d --with-isl --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-install-libiberty --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-werror gdc_include_dir=/usr/include/dlang/gdc
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.1.0 (GCC) 
configure:3095: $? = 0
configure:3084: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3095: $? = 1
configure:3084: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3095: $? = 1
configure:3115: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3137: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3141: $? = 0
configure:3189: result: yes
configure:3192: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3194: result: a.out
configure:3200: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3207: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3211: $? = 0
configure:3233: result: 
configure:3255: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3263: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
conftest.c:9:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <stdio.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:3267: $? = 1
configure:3274: ./conftest
./configure: line 3276: ./conftest: No such file or directory
configure:3278: $? = 127
configure:3285: error: in `/home/deck/gap/gap-4.11.1':
configure:3287: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_ABI_set=
ac_cv_env_ABI_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_GMP_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GMP_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GMP_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GMP_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_ZLIB_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_ZLIB_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_ZLIB_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_ZLIB_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ABI=''
ABI_CFLAGS=''
AR=''
AS=''
AWK=''
BOEHM_GC_CPPFLAGS=''
BOEHM_GC_LDFLAGS=''
BOEHM_GC_LIBS=''
BUILD_BOEHM_GC=''
BUILD_GMP=''
BUILD_LIBATOMIC_OPS=''
BUILD_ZLIB=''
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=''
COMPAT_MODE=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GAPARCH=''
GAP_RELEASEDAY='2021-03-02'
GAP_RELEASEYEAR='2021'
GAP_VERSION='4.11.1'
GC_SOURCES=''
GMP_CPPFLAGS=''
GMP_LDFLAGS=''
GMP_LIBS=''
GREP=''
HPCGAP=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
JULIA=''
JULIA_CPPFLAGS=''
JULIA_LDFLAGS=''
JULIA_LIBS=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBATOMIC_OPS_CPPFLAGS=''
LIBATOMIC_OPS_LDFLAGS=''
LIBATOMIC_OPS_LIBS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAINTAINER_MODE=''
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='support@gap-system.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='GAP'
PACKAGE_STRING='GAP 4.11.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='gap-4.11.1'
PACKAGE_URL='https://www.gap-system.org/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='4.11.1'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PTHREAD_CC=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
RANLIB=''
READLINE_CPPFLAGS=''
READLINE_LDFLAGS=''
READLINE_LIBS=''
SED=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
SYS_IS_CYGWIN32=''
SYS_IS_DARWIN=''
WARN_CFLAGS=''
WARN_CXXFLAGS=''
ZLIB_CPPFLAGS=''
ZLIB_LDFLAGS=''
ZLIB_LIBS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ax_pthread_config=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
gap_kernel_major_version=''
gap_kernel_minor_version=''
gapdir=''
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
wincygbin=''
wingapdir=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GAP"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gap-4.11.1"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.11.1"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GAP 4.11.1"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "support@gap-system.org"
#define PACKAGE_URL "https://www.gap-system.org/"

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: `conftest.c:9:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <stdio.h>` this is very odd, there's something wrong with your linux installation. Does the file `/usr/include/stdio.h` exists?

Comment: Very strange where you have a compiler but not one of the needed header files. I can't remember if `stdio.h` is part of GCC or GLIBC (the compiler can't find that header file which leads to the error). Perhaps you have missed some essential development package installation?

Comment: You should probably look through the excellent [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org) to see what it says about C development and what packages you need to install for it to work.

Comment: im having this issue trying to compile python 3.8 on deck via pyenv

Comment: You might need to install the following packages (*after disabling readonly mode*): `sudo pacman -S base-devel glibc linux-api-headers`

Answer (score 0):

non answer

/usr/include is simply missing on steam deck. meaning building programs on deck is likely a nonstarter.

some recon notes

- sudo requires a password, set by opening the graphical system configuration panel, users, Steam Deck User, set password
- `sudo pacman -Fy; sudo pacman -F studio.h` shows that gcc is installed and provides this file, even though the file is missing. note that after applying a steamdeck system update, the populated pacman database was removed. probably even if we could repair the missing /use/include directory, it would not be stable
- `find / -iname studio.h 2>/dev/null` confirms that this fine is missing, not hidden somewhere usual
- enabling developer mode in game mode -> settings -> developer mode. did not restore these missing files.

conclusions? we're probably expected to build bins on other computers and install them on deck, so I hope we have another computer and a good idea how to package and install software. SteamDeck appears to promote using flatpak exclusively.

otherwise does anyone have a good chroot bootstrap recipe for steam deck? I tried a chroot but it didn't execute and I'm not sure why

```
mkdir steamdeck-dev
tar -C / -c /etc/pacman* /usr/bin/pacman | tar -C steamdeck-dev -xv
sudo chroot stramdeck-dev /use/bin/pacman
```

"chroot failed to run command" :/